# How to write mock for unitofwork pattern

Tags: .net, mocking, unit-of-work, xunit.net

I want to write mock for below code. GetAllAsync(Expression<Func<T,bool>>predicate=null,Func<IQueryable,IOrderedQueryable>orderBy=null,List<Expression<Func<T,object>>>includes=null,bool disableTracking = true);

Please guide

```
    var includes1 = new List<Expression<Func<Order, object>>>() { x => x.OrderDetails };
_unitOfWork.Setup(uow => uow.Order.GetAllAsync(r => r.CompanyId  == companyId,null,includes1,true)).Returns(GetAllOrders());
```

GetAllorders retruns the order list as wanted

Comment: Can we please get a [mcve]?

Comment: Dont mock your uow, stub your data that it pulls from